# Specific way of positioning in Bootstrap

Tags: css, positioning, rows

Let's say I have two divs with a class of "row" and and I want the second one to always be on the very bottom of the div with a class of "section"(bottom: 0).

Here is the code to illustrate it better:

```
<div class="section">
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

The div with a class of "section" has a height of 100vh
The first row's takes about 70% of the screen's height and I want the second row to always be on the bottom of the page but also to not interfere with the first row's content when the screen's height will get smaller. How can I try to position those divs ?

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: bootstrap is a row layout framework and for aligning something vertically you will have to write CSS not related to bootstrap..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. Adding content to the first row will push the second row down if its larger than the height of the viewport. On very small screens you will get a vertical body scrollbar as normal.

http://codepen.io/dherran/pen/KzYqmW

```css
body, html {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.section {
  height: 100vh;
}

.row:first-child {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  min-height: calc(100% - 40px);
}

.row:nth-child(2) {
  background: blue;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

I would avoid using nth() selectors for this. Use classes instead. The use of these selectors are only for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is what I wanted to do.